# Java How to send data over network VIA a UI button

Tags: java, sockets, multiplayer

I'm learning about sockets and how server/client communicates.

So far, I have my protocols figured out and managed to simulate a synthetic TCP three-way-handshake:

1. Client successfully connects to server and sends SYN.
2. Server receives SYN and replies SYNACK to client.
3. Client receives SYNACK, and replies ACK to server.

Thats it, all this is linearly executed in the Run() method under a while(true) loop of my Runnable client service in a new Thread. I don't know how a Button in the GUI class can tell my Client Service to send a specific packet when, say, a specific button in the UI is pressed while the service runs in a different thread.

I have an idea but correct me on this: somehow add ActionListeners for all the buttons in my GUI inside the Service class instead of the GUI..

Thanks.

PS. I'm using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to read/write data from/to socket stream.

ClientService.java:

```
public class ClientService implements Runnable, GameProtocol    {
    private Socket socket;
    private int clientNumber;
    private GameClient client;
    private JTextArea clientConsole;
    private DataInputStream fromServer;
    private DataOutputStream toServer;

    public ClientService(Socket aSocket, GameClient aClient, JTextArea textArea)    {
        this.socket = aSocket;
        this.client = aClient;
        this.clientConsole = textArea;
    }
    private void buildStreams() throws Exception    {
        this.fromServer = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
        this.toServer = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    public void sendPacket(int data)    {
        try     {
            this.toServer.writeInt(data);
        }   catch   (Exception e)   {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
    public void flushPacket()   {
        try     {
            this.toServer.flush();
        }   catch   (Exception e)   {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    public void run()   {
        try {
            try {
                buildStreams();
                toServer.writeInt(PLAYER_SYN);  // start synthetic three way handshake
                toServer.flush();
                if(fromServer.readInt() == SERVER_SYNACK)   {
                    this.clientNumber = fromServer.readInt();
                    clientConsole.append("Client number from Server: " + clientNumber + "\n");
                    toServer.writeInt(PLAYER_ACK);
                    toServer.writeInt(this.clientNumber);
                    toServer.flush();
                }
                else    {
                    clientConsole.append("Client -> Server Sync failed. Can't proceed.\n");
                    toServer.writeInt(PLAYER_QUIT);
                    toServer.flush();
                    socket.close();
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                executeCommand();
            }   finally {   
                socket.close();
            }
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Client Service: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void executeCommand() throws Exception  {
        boolean quit = false;
        while(!quit)    {
            int command = -14324;
            if(fromServer.available() > 0)  {
                command = fromServer.readInt();
            }
            switch (command)    {
                case WINNER:
                    clientConsole.append("You Win.\n");
                    break;
                case LOSER:
                    clientConsole.append("You Lost.\n");
                    break;
                case ENABLE_TURN:
                    client.enableTurn();
                    break;
                case DISABLE_TURN:
                    client.disableTurn();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameClient.java:

```
public class GameClient extends JFrame implements GameProtocol  {
/**
 * TextArea size.
 */
    private final int 
        TEXTAREA_ROWS = 5,
        TEXTAREA_COLS = 40;
/**
 * Client window size, unadjustable.
 */
    private final int 
        FRAME_W = 535,
        FRAME_H = 600;  

    // for Assignment 10
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream toServer;          
    private DataInputStream fromServer;
/**
 * ArrayList of type Cards, by default, holds 20 cards.
 */
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;
/**
 * Console for debugging.
 */
    private JTextArea gameConsole;
/**
 * Button to terminate game
 */
    private JButton quitButton;
/**
 * Main Frame panels, cardsPanel and consolePanel are sub-panels of mainPanel.
 */
    private JPanel mainPanel, cardsPanel, consolePanel;
/**
 * Builds packets to be sent to the server
 */
    private Packet packet;
/**
 * players points, accumulated.
 */
    private int points = 0;
/**
 * card choice 1
 */
    private int choice1 = -1;
/**
 * card choice 2
 */
    private int choice2 = -1;
/**
 * for building packet arguments
 */
    private static int packetBuilderCount = 0;
/**
 * Counter for outbound and inbound packets
 */
    private static int packetNumber = 1;
/**
 * for timing out cards when recieving no match
 */
    private Timer timer;
/**
 * true when user is allowed to pick cards.
 * false when another user is true
 */
    private boolean isTurn = true;
    // service
    private ClientService service;
/**
 * default contrustor. Builds JFrame and all components.
 */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new GameClient();
    }
    public GameClient() {
        packet = new Packet();
        buildButton();
        buildCards();
        addEventToCards();      // adds actionlistener to each card.
        buildPanel();
        buildTimer();
        buildFrame();
        buildConnection();  // for assignment 10            
    }
    private void buildConnection()  {
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
//          this.toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//          this.fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            gameConsole.append("Socket Connected\n");
            service = new ClientService(socket, this, this.gameConsole);
            new Thread(service).start();

        }   catch   (SecurityException ex)  {
            System.out.println("Check your firewall or antivirus. Unable to establish connection to server.");
        }   catch   (UnknownHostException ex)   {
            System.out.println("Host can't be found. Unable to establish connection to server.");
        }   catch   (ConnectException ex)   {
            System.out.println("Connection refused. What now?");
            ex.printStackTrace();
//          ex.printStackTrace();
        }   catch   (IOException ex)    {
            System.out.println("fuck......");
        }
    }
/**
 * initializes the timer.
 */
    private void buildTimer()   {
        int delay = 3000;   // wait for 3000ms
        timer = new Timer(delay, new AbstractAction() {
/**
 * event handler for timer. Flips the cards back to face down position.
 */
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                flipCard(choice1, 10);      
                flipCard(choice2, 10);
            }
        });
    }
/**
 * Initializes JFrame
 */
    private void buildFrame()   {
        this.setSize(FRAME_W, FRAME_H);
        setResizable(false);
        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
/**
 * Initializes and compiles panels together. Adds Cards to panels
 */
    private void buildPanel()   {
        gameConsole = new JTextArea(TEXTAREA_ROWS, TEXTAREA_COLS);
        JScrollPane scrollConsole = new JScrollPane(gameConsole);
        scrollConsole.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        gameConsole.setEditable(false);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(535, 475));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        cardsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 5, 20, 20));
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            cardsPanel.add(this.cards.get(i));
        }
        consolePanel = new JPanel();
        consolePanel.add(scrollConsole);
        consolePanel.add(quitButton);
        mainPanel.add(cardsPanel);
        mainPanel.add(consolePanel);
    }
/**
 * builds quit button, adds action listener to handle click
 */
    private void buildButton()  {
        quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        quitButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            buildQuitPacket();
        });
    }
/**
 * builds 20 Card object.
 */
    private void buildCards()   {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        Card temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            temp = new Card();
            cards.add(temp);
        }
    }
/**
 * adds actionlistener to all 20 card objects.
 */
    private void addEventToCards()  {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            final int INDEX = i;
            cards.get(i).addActionListener(e -> buildButtonPacket(this.cards.get(INDEX).getId()));
        }
    }
/**
 * Builds and sends a Packet when a card is chosen
 * @param value The card ID which was chosen.
 */
    private void buildButtonPacket(int value)   {
        if(!isTurn) {
            this.gameConsole.append("Its not you're turn.\n");
            return;
        }
        if(packetBuilderCount == 0) {
            packet.writeCommandToPacket(PICKED_CARDS);
            packet.writeValueToPacket(value);
            packetBuilderCount++;
            choice1 = value;
        }
        else if(packetBuilderCount == 1)    {
            packet.writeValueToPacket(value);
            packetBuilderCount = 0;
            writeToConsoleOutBound(packet.toString());
            choice2 = value;
//          try{
//              out.print(this.packet.getPacket());
//              out.flush();
//          }   catch   (Exception e)   {
//              gameConsole.append("could not send packet.\n");
//          }
            packet.clearPacket();
        }
    }
/**
 * For handling commands from recieved Packet
 * @param recieved the Packet object recieved. Gets and handles command and possible arguments that follows.
 * See GameProtocol class for packet command definitions.
 */
    public void handlePacket(Packet recieved)   {
        int cmd = recieved.getCommand();
        writeToConsoleInBound(recieved.toString());
        int arg1 = -99;
        int arg2 = -99;
        switch (cmd)    {
            case SERVER_SYNACK:
                arg1 = recieved.getFirstArg();
                if(arg1 == 1)   {
                    this.isTurn = true;
                }
                else if (arg1 == 0) {
                    this.isTurn = false;
                }
                else    {
                    writeToConsoleError("Server sync failed. Terminating..");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    }   catch   (InterruptedException ex)   {
                        writeToConsoleError(ex.getMessage());
                    }   finally {
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case CARDMATCH:
                arg1 = recieved.getFirstArg();
                arg2 = recieved.getSecondArg();
                if(arg1 > 9)    {
                    arg1 = 9;
                }
                if(arg2 > 9)    {
                    arg2 = 9;
                }
                flipCard(choice1, arg1);
                flipCard(choice2, arg2);
                break;
            case CARDNOMATCH:
//              System.out.println("CLIENT: im going to sleep");
                arg1 = recieved.getFirstArg();
                arg2 = recieved.getSecondArg();
                if(arg1 > 9)    {
                    arg1 = 9;
                }
                if(arg2 > 9)    {
                    arg2 = 9;
                }
                flipCard(choice1, arg1);
                flipCard(choice2, arg2);
                this.cardsPanel.revalidate();
                this.cardsPanel.repaint();
                this.consolePanel.revalidate();
                this.consolePanel.repaint();
                timer.setRepeats(false);    //the timer should only go off once
                timer.start();
                break;
            case SHOW_CARD:
                arg1 = recieved.getFirstArg();
                arg2 = recieved.getSecondArg();
                if(arg1 < 0 || arg1 > 19)   {
                    writeToConsoleError(" BAD PACKET ARGUMENT 1, \nCard index out of bounds");
                }
                else if(arg2 < 0 || arg2 > 10)  {
                    writeToConsoleError(" BAD PACKET ARGUMENT 2, \nImage index out of bounds");
                }
                else    {
                    flipCard(arg1, arg2);
                }
                break;
            case ENABLE_TURN:
                this.isTurn = true;
                break;
            case DISABLE_TURN:
                this.isTurn = false;
                break;
            case WINNER:
                this.gameConsole.append("You win!\n");
                break;
            case LOSER:
                this.gameConsole.append("You lost :( \n");
                break;
            case ADD_POINTS:
                arg1 = recieved.getFirstArg();
                this.points += arg1;
                this.gameConsole.append("** Gained " + Integer.toString(arg1) + ", you now have " + Integer.toString(this.points) + " points.\n");
                break;
            case OTHER_QUIT:
                this.gameConsole.append("Other player forfeited. You win!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
/**
 * Builds a packet containing QUIT when quit button is pressed
 * Only available when isTurn == true.
 */
    private void buildQuitPacket()  {
        if(this.isTurn == false)    {
            this.gameConsole.append("You can only quit when it is your turn.");
            return;
        }
        service.sendPacket(PLAYER_QUIT);
        service.flushPacket();
//      this.service.sendPacket(PLAYER_QUIT);
//      this.service.flushPacket();
        System.exit(0);
    }
/**
 * Writes the outgoing packet to the game console.
 * @param msg the actual packet message.
 */
    public void writeToConsoleOutBound(String msg)  {
        this.gameConsole.append(Integer.toString(packetNumber++) + ": SENDING: " + msg + "\n");
    }
/**
 * Writes the incoming packet to the game console.
 * @param msg the actual packet message.
 */
    public void writeToConsoleInBound(String msg)   {
        this.gameConsole.append(Integer.toString(packetNumber++) + ": RECEIVING: " + msg + "\n");
    }
/**
 * Writes an error to the game console.
 * @param msg the error message.
 */
    public void writeToConsoleError(String msg) {
        this.gameConsole.append("Error handling packet number " + Integer.toString(packetNumber) + "." + msg + "\n");
    }
/**
 * Flips a Card object and show an image
 * @param whichCard the card ID which will be flipped.
 * @param imgID the image which will be shown on the flipped card.
 */
    public void flipCard(int whichCard, int imgID)  {
        this.cards.get(whichCard).flipCard(imgID);
    }
/**
 * Accumulates points.
 * @param amt the amount to be added.
 */
    public void gainPoints(int amt) {
        this.points += amt;
    }
    public void enableTurn()    {
        this.isTurn = true;
    }
    public void disableTurn()   {
        this.isTurn = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The button needs a listener that feeds the background thread to perform the network i/o or any long running operation on behalf of the ui. From there you can mix and match as needed

Comment: @efekctive When you say "feeds the background thread", do you imply that the Service thread is an instance of the GUI class?

Comment: No. The moment you make a socket connection from the ui, it will freeze the UI. It is a runnable/thread. Conversely, when you want to pass info back to the UI you need to invoke any of the async methods that UIs have

Comment: Start with [JavaFx](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm).

Comment: I've managed to send a packet VIA a button press inside my GUI.
I ended up having an instance of the client service inside my GUI class and initialized the service in a new thread and since the GUI and the service runs asynchronously, it's not freezing the GUI. Do you guys think this implementation is valid?

Comment: Post the code. It helps to look at it

Comment: @efekctive Posted, sorry it's a bit long, and I haven't finished handling the received protocols in ClientService.

Comment: Can you point the line in the GUI where you launch the service?

Comment: @efekctive in the void method buildConnection(), which gets called in the GameClient() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to a socket works because it is in a constructor, no calls to modify a rendered element have been made (say update a button's text). Your client service needs a loop waiting for requests made by the UI, otherwise you would need to create a thread with every request made by the UI. It will become a bottleneck, specially in a game when one user action can trigger several UI updates. Look at the code posted you should follow more or less that pattern

```
package so;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class ClientService implements Runnable{
    JLabel label; 
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> work;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Long i = null;
        try{
            while(true){
                if ((i = work.poll()) != null){
                    final long ii = i;
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            label.setText(ii + "");
                        }
                      });
                }
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x){

        }
    }

}

class GameClient extends JFrame{

    Thread worker;
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> work;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    GameClient(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        label = new JLabel("Label");
        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                work.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
        this.add(label);
        this.add(button);
        work = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long>();
        ClientService cs = new ClientService();
        cs.label = this.label;
        cs.work = this.work;
        this.worker = new Thread(cs);
        this.worker.start();
    }
}

class SOCLass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SOCLass m = new SOCLass();
        GameClient frame = new GameClient();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.worker.interrupt();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```